# Gain value for PI controller using Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am doing project in Matlab Simulink. I want to find the proportional and integral gain value for PI controller. Is there any way to find the PI controller gain value which does not have transfer function? I  have two inputs for PI controller one is the  the reference voltage and  and the other is voltage from the capacitor. Please help me in finding the gain value.

Please let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use PID Tuner in MATLAB/SIMULINK. PID Tuner provides a fast and widely applicable single-loop PID tuning method for the Simulink PID Controller blocks. With this method, you can tune PID parameters to achieve a robust design with the desired response time. Here you can find a rather good [[example]](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/pidtune.html).

But if you know the transfer function of your system you can easily use something like this:

```
sys = zpk([],[-1 -1 -1],1); % define the plant
[C_pi,info] = pidtune(sys,'pi')
```

Comment: I am using MATLAB 2010a , I am unable to find the PID tuner block in this version. I used PI controller for this purpose but I am unable to find the gain value without a transfer function. How to proceed? Please help me to find the PI controller gain value which does not have transfer function in Matlab 2010a version

Comment: you can check this link:   http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29983-z-n-pid-controller-tuning

Comment: @BasSwinckels I edited the link. The documentation center in Matlab is re-structured recently. Thanks for mentioning.